# KerasRegressor (much) worse than MLPRegressor?

Tags: scikit-learn, regression, keras

I'm comparing `KerasRegressor` with scikit-learn's `MLPRegressor` and the former seems to be performing much worse under similar conditions. Or am I missing something very basic?

Here's the [Gist](https://gist.github.com/bacalfa/c8a37feb7e9443f0fc5797bd29c797b5). Necessary data files are [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=68705349221716481246) and [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=04413976163200662185).

The output is given below:

```
MLPRegressor
============
r2_score: 0.9498015043626485
mean_absolute_error: 1.2375251067546698
mean_squared_error: 3.1270623572484233
median_absolute_error: 0.8439709890654576
mean_absolute_percentage_error: 5.716115241892469

KerasRegressor
==============
r2_score: -0.21815826719358755
mean_absolute_error: 6.447014662587636
mean_squared_error: 75.8838848484866
median_absolute_error: 4.708965668576953
mean_absolute_percentage_error: 27.069446468540352
```

In addition, I get several warnings like:

```
/home/bacalfa/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:122: DeprecationWarning: Estimator KerasRegressor modifies parameters in __init__. This behavior is deprecated as of 0.18 and support for this behavior will be removed in 0.20.
```

Relevant modules' versions:

```
Keras==2.0.0
numpy==1.12.0
scipy==0.19.0
sklearn==0.18.1
tensorflow==1.0.1
tensorflow-gpu==1.0.1
Theano==0.9.0rc4
```

**EDIT**

After editing file `~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/wrappers/scikit_learn.py` as indicated [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/5577), I still got bad results. But after removing `mae`, `mape`, and `msle` from the list of `loss` options (i.e., I only consider `mse`) I finally got more decent results. I added some timing variables as well and updated the Gist file. Not sure why those loss options are causing problems...

```
MLPRegressor
============
Time: 63.069955586000106
Score: 0.9743374210376049
Parameters: {'solver': 'lbfgs', 'nesterovs_momentum': True, 'momentum': 0.95582961730267013, 'learning_rate_init': 6.9585889749848416e-05, 'learning_rate': 'invscaling', 'hidden_layer_sizes': (13,), 'beta_2': 0.54401214785115037, 'beta_1': 0.49106283542759821, 'alpha': 1.7176826485217918, 'activation': 'logistic'}
r2_score: 0.9498015043626485
mean_absolute_error: 1.2375251067546698
mean_squared_error: 3.1270623572484233
median_absolute_error: 0.8439709890654576
mean_absolute_percentage_error: 5.716115241892469

KerasRegressor
==============
Time: 111.47958513100002
Score: -7.324164294960475
Parameters: {'units': 9, 'optimizer': 'adamax', 'nesterov': False, 'momentum': 0.3903057105612151, 'lr': 0.012612536273812315, 'loss': 'mse', 'kernel_regularizer_weight': 0.049702772055240763, 'kernel_regularizer': 'l1_l2', 'kernel_initializer': 'normal', 'beta_2': 0.31764966762573782, 'beta_1': 0.055241532426840559, 'activation': 'relu'}
r2_score: 0.9353675562984648
mean_absolute_error: 1.4353763767225414
mean_squared_error: 4.026209932985799
median_absolute_error: 1.1217291129910958
mean_absolute_percentage_error: 6.831308588574378
```

Comment: I think that's because of https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/5577 which causes grid search to maximize the loss when using KerasRegressor instead of minimizing it.

Comment: Thanks! I edited the original question reflecting that.

Comment: When editing KerasRegressor, did you edit both lines which return loss? It seems that if you're using more than one loss function, you're getting bad results, which is the case if you edited only the last line.

Comment: I edited both lines, `return loss[0]` and `return loss`. This is why I find it strange.